# Radon measure with lebesgue decomposition

Tags: measure-theory

Assume that we have a finite Radon measure $\mu$ on a LCH space $X$.
Let $M(X)$ denote the space of all complex regular Borel measure on $X$ with norm $\lVert v \rVert = |v|(X)$. Let $v \in M(X)$ with lebesgue decomposition $v_a$ and $v_b$ respect to $\mu$. Clearly, $v_a$ and $v_b$ are also Radon measures. I'm curious that do we have $\lVert v \rVert = \lVert v_a \rVert + \lVert v_b \rVert$?

Thanks.

Comment: @Masacroso yes, LCH means locally compact hausdorff.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. Do you mean $\lVert v \rVert = |v|(X)$? If not, what is $x$?

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Yes you are right. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose $\nu_a$ stands for the absolutely continuous part and $\nu_b$ for then singular part.

$\|\mu+\nu\|=\|\mu\|+\|\nu\|$ if $\mu \perp \nu$. In Lebesgue decompostion we do have $\nu_a \perp \nu_b$. Hence, $\|\nu\|=\|\nu_a\|+\|\nu_b\|$.

Comment: Do we have a proof for why $\|\mu+\nu\|=\|\mu\|+\|\nu\|$ if $\mu \perp \nu$?

Comment: @GGCat, by definition, $\mu \perp \nu$ means there are sets $E$ and $F$ so that $|\mu|(E) = |\mu|(X)$, $|\nu|(F) = |\nu|(X)$, and $|\mu|(E) = |\nu|(F) = 0$. This implies $|\mu + \nu| = |\mu| + |\nu|$.